# How do I convert a string to a double in Python?

Tags: python, string, double

I would like to know how to convert a string containing digits to a double.

Comment: That is not a python double. A python double has unlimited capacity.

Answer (score 392):

```
>>> x = "2342.34"
>>> float(x)
2342.3400000000001
```

There you go.  Use float (which behaves like and has the same precision as a C,C++, or Java double).

Comment: Or, more specifically, Python floats are C doubles.

Comment: Bah used float instead of double. now my code is off by .0000000001 which hurts

Comment: incidentally, this also works with exponent notation. eg: `float('7.5606e-08')` produces the expected python float.

Comment: With my python (version 2.7.10), when I assign
`>>> x = "2342.34"`  and convert to float `>>> float(x) `
I get `2342.34` instead the `2342.3400000000001` reported by @Mongoose

Comment: Use `>>> 0.1 + 0.2` for double. `>>> 0.1 + 0.6` for float.

Answer (score 57):

The decimal operator might be more in line with what you are looking for:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = "234243.434"
>>> print Decimal(x)
234243.434
```

Comment: The returned thing is a Decimal(...), not a simple number.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that if your string number contains more than 15 significant  digits `float(s)` will round it.In those cases it is better to use `Decimal`

Here is an explanation and some code samples: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info