# How do I convert a string into a decimal number for arithmetic manipulation in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Similar posts such as the following do not answer my question. 
[Convert a string to integer with decimal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094717/convert-a-string-to-integer-with-decimal-in-python)

Consider the following Python code.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> s = '23.456'
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(s)
>>> d
Decimal('23.456')           # How do I represent this as simply 23.456?
>>> d - 1
22                          # How do I obtain the output to be 22.456?
```

How do I convert a string to a decimal number, so I am able to perform arithmetic functions on it and obtain an output with the correct precision?

Comment: Looks like a previous question. Use float().

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482410/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-double-in-python

Comment: What's wrong with `x = float(23.456) - 1`.

Comment: Right, float is not Decimal. I thought float was not as precise.

Comment: The differences between `Decimal` and `float` are outlined here: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Comment: `Decimal` is more "precise" at representing decimal (base 10) numbers; `float` is more precise at representing binary (base 2) numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay in `decimal` numbers, safest is to convert everything:

```
>>> s = '23.456'
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(s)

>>> d - decimal.Decimal('1')
Decimal('22.456')
>>> d - decimal.Decimal('1.0')
Decimal('22.456')
```

In Python 2.7, there's an implicit conversion for integers, but not floats.

```
>>> d - 1
Decimal('22.456')
>>> d - 1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the `Decimal` required for your computations? The [Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) doc outlines their differences. If not, you could just do

```
 d = float('23.456')
 d
 23.456

 d - 1
 22.456
```

Oddly enough re `Decimal`, I get this interactively

```
d = decimal.Decimal('23.456')

d
Decimal('23.456')
d - 1
Decimal('22.456')
```

But when I print it, I get the values

```
print d
23.456
print d-1
22.456
```

Comment: float is NOT the same thing: float('100000000.0') + float('0.000000001') is 100000000.0

Comment: @wroniasty I did NOT claim it was, I simply asked if it was required. The differences between the two are outlined quite clearly here: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Comment: @wroniasty: If OP is working with decimals to the thousandths place, I don't really see it making that much of a difference.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference: float(1e15) + float('0.001') is 1e15

Comment: There are a lot of reasons to use decimal instead of float.  For example, there is really no good reason to use floating point numbers for financial arithmetic, and in some places the legal requirements make a floating point implementation quite difficult compared to a decimal implementation.

Comment: The code `decimal.Decimal(float('23.456'))` is fairly lossy.  The `float` call doesn't add anything, and it actually removes the precision information from the string.  You should never use `Decimal(float(x))`.

Comment: `>>> print d` vs `>>> d` is the difference between `str` and `repr` <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python>

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifically TRYING specifically to use the Decimal arbitrary precision library or are you just struggling to convert a string to a Python float?

If you are TRYING to use Decimal:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> s1='23.456'
>>> s2='1.0'
>>> decimal.Decimal(s1) - decimal.Decimal(s2)
Decimal('22.456')
>>> s1='23.456'
>>> s2='1'
>>> decimal.Decimal(s1) - decimal.Decimal(s2)
Decimal('22.456')
```

Or, what I think is more likely, you are trying to just convert a string to a Python floating point value:

```
>>> s1='23.456'
>>> s2='1'
>>> float(s1)-float(s2)
22.456
>>> float(s1)-1
22.456
>>> float(s1)-1.0
22.456
```

Comment: converting into float is easy

Answer (score 0):

Use the bultin float function:

```
>>> d = float('23.456')
>>> d
23.456
>>> d - 1
22.456
```

See the docs here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float

Comment: I thought float is not as precise. Would this be a valid solution if the number required much greater precision?

Comment: In python a float is equivalent to a c double. How much precision do you need?

Comment: float('100000000.0') + float('0.000000001') is 100000000.0 so I gues it's not a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

My Python seems to do it differently:

```
>>> s = '23.456'
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(s)
>>> d
Decimal('23.456')
>>> d-1
Decimal('22.456')
```

What version/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If using float, when the number gets too large -- **x = 29345678.91 for example** -- you get results that you might not expect.  In this case, `float(x)` becomes **2.934567891E7** which seems undesirable especially if working with financial numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In python, to convert a value string to float just do it:

```
num = "29.0"
print (float(num))
```

To convert string to decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = "29.0"
print (Decimal(num))
```