# Converting the input of DecimalField of WTForm to a float?-Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask-wtforms

The input I give to a DecimalField of WTFform in Flask application is being converted to a string. I need it be an int or float in order to perform any
mathematical operation?

Any help would be appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a double in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482410/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-double-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`wtforms.DecimalField` produces a [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instance.

```
>>> import wtforms
>>> from webob.multidict import MultiDict
>>> class F(wtforms.Form):
...     foo = wtforms.DecimalField()
... 
>>> f = F(formdata=MultiDict(foo=3.45))
>>> val = f.data['foo']
>>> val
Decimal('3.45000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125')
>>> type(val)
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

The object can be used in calculations:

```
>>> val * 4
Decimal('13.80000000000000071054273576')
>>> val + 2
Decimal('5.450000000000000177635683940')
```

or can be converted to a float or int using the respective builtin functions

```
>>> float(val)
3.45
>>> int(val)
3
```